# Copy range A:AM in sheet 3 instead of entire row and paste in sheet1 (A1) one below the other

Tags: vba

How do I make a change in the code so that it copies only range A:AM in sheet3 till the last row in column D, instead of copying the entire row and paste it in Sheet1 (A1) one below the other?

```
Option Explicit 
Public Sub ABC()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 7 To LastRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(3).Range("J" & iRow  & ":AM" & iRow)) <> 0 Then
            Sheets(3).Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Sheets(3).Range("A" & iRow & ":AM" & iRow).Copy
```

or

```
Sheets(3).Cells(irow, "A").Resize(1, 39).Copy
```

or

```
Sheets(3).Range("A:AM").Rows(iRow).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

***If your goal is to replace the loop with a entire range copy/paste all at once then:***

Create a variable to store the last row index based off column `D` and then just create your dynamic range to copy accordingly

---

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row          '<-- Find Last Row
ws.Range("A1:AM" & lr).Copy                               '<-- Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues   '<-- Paste
```

Comment: Once you posted solution I thought that too! But the question seems to say OP wants to copy all at once `instead of copying .... one below the other` which I read as getting rid of the loop altogether and just replacing the filter component with a `Column D` last row indicator. Either way, one of these should do the trick :)

Comment: Yes I see now it could be that